# How do you prefix all $http requests with http://localhost:3001?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My web server is on `http://localhost:3000`, but my API server is on `http://localhost:3001`. So instead of prefacing all my requests like so:

```
var root = 'http://localhost:3001';
$http.get(root+'/')...
```

... how can I set `http://localhost:3001` as the default for all outgoing `$http` requests? I tried looking at [Default Transformations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), but couldn't understand it.

Edit: After reading the docs a bit more carefully, I'm less confident (but still unsure) that Angular has a way to handle this. It seems that you could manipulate the headers and data, but not the url.

Edit 2: Two answerers recommended using global functions/variables. This works, but leads to CORS errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on wheter your doing your requests from one js file or across several you could either

```
//Create 2 global variables first outside the function then just use the 
// var name when needed
var web = "http://localhost:3001";
var api = "http://localhost:3000";
```

Or if you need to do requests across multiple js files you could create functions to return each var, then call them when needed. Just remember the file with the functios will need to be loaded first.

```
function web() {
    return "http://localhost:3001";
}

function api() {
    return "http://localhost:3000";
}
```

so then it would be

```
$http.get(api + '/')...
```

or

```
$http.get(api() + '/')...
```

**Edit: Update For your additional issues**

The POST request is being preflighted by your browser with the OPTIONS request, and won't send a real request to the server if it gets no approval, which is expected COR behavhour and is detailed more in the COR docs.

There is a few ways to fix this, but one common way is to add a header to your request:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3001/users',
    user= { 'someKey': 'some value' },
    config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        }
   }
};

$http.post(url,user,config);
```

Comment: @AdamZerner on a side note, what advantages would you hope to get using 2 servers here? I didn't think 2 servers would be much extra CORS work than a single server, but I have never tried myself.

Comment: Someone recommended it to me as a way to be more efficient. My understanding: let X = web and let Y = API. Say I'm serving X and Y from the same server but am getting a lot of API hits so I need to scale Y. Given the setup, every time I add a server I'd be adding X *and* Y, when I only need Y. Separating X and Y into different servers gives you flexibility as you scale. But the question we're asking ourselves is "is the flexibility worth the complexity", and we both seem to think the answer is "no".

Comment: @AdamZerner interesting,I've never come across that myself before. Perhaps the benefits only become apparent once you scale up an awful lot to a point where the actual server hardware performance starts to be affected splitting the work would reduce the strain on the server?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it'd take a lot of scaling for this to be an issue, but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a global function that handles the prefixing for you, e.g

```
function p(uri) {
    return "http://localhost:3001" + uri;
}

...

$http.get( p('/') );
```

Comment: Yeah. That seems like a solid option if Angular doesn't have a good way to handle it.

Comment: Actually, that leads to requests that look like this `http://localhost:3000/$http://localhost:3001/users` :/. Related note: `$http.post('http://localhost:3001/users', user)` was send successfully as an `OPTIONS` request and gave me a `200`, but didn't create the user.

Comment: @AdamZerner can you show the full code for how your making the request?

Comment: `$http.post(p('/users'), user)` + Dai's exact function for `p` in my `app.js` file.

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry - my `p` function mistakenly said `return '$http://localhost:3001' + uri;`. But now I'm getting a CORS error.